# Set user account picture and dis-allow changes

Tags: windows-7, registry, policy

I am running some changes to the registry of the small number of computers in our group.

In Windows 7 Enterprise, how can I disable the ability for the user to change the user account picture?

I do not want an empty frame on the Start menu or on the log-on screen. I want our company logo to display, and I don't want it to be able to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Apply the default user logon picture to all users' in the group policy is stated right in the description of it that it is supposed to do what I want, but it does not perform as advertised.

This [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/itprovistadesktopui/thread/aad99c0e-17cd-41ec-af56-1c5a4f3c5ea9/) indicates that this is a known bug in Vista, and I cannot find any evidence yet that the bug has been fixed in Windows 7.

My research seems to indicate that what I want to do is not possible without quite a lot of fooling around.

Comment: The "Apply the defaul user logon picture..." setting in GPO works in Windows Server 2008 R2. I would expect that it also works in Win7.

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=18c90c80-8b0a-4906-a4f5-ff24cc2030fb&displaylang=en) I found **Apply the default user logon picture to all users**

[Here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/default-logon-picture-all-users-in-vista/) is a detailed description.

Comment: This didn't work.  I just get a blank logon and startmenu picture frame.  Some further research indicates that this was a known bug in Vista, and I can find an indication that it was fixed in Windows 7.